# how can i fix errors about import in my code

Tags: python, importerror

```
from app import app
```

When i do this, the error occurs.

```
E:\python\python.exe "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/dash exercise/dash-test/apps/Spreads.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):



 File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/dash exercise/dash-test/apps/Spreads.py", line 19, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (E:\python\lib\site-packages\app\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need `import app`.

It appears you're using PyCharm, so here's another tip. In the code itself, you can try to remove the import statement from the top of the file, and then, wherever the reference is in your code, it should have a red underline to indicate an error --In this case, a missing import. You can put your cursor on the red-underlined word, and press ⌥ ↩ on MacOS or Alt+Enter on Windows, and PyCharm will import the reference correctly for you. This is expecially useful when you have a complicated module structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing app instead of from app import app do import app

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import app
```

If you want use function from app import for example you do:

```
app.name_of_function()
```

If you only need few functions from app import you can do:

```
from app import name_of_function, name_of_function2
```

And you can use

```
name_of_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, doing `import app` should fix the issue.

Why is that? Because when you're doing `from app import app` your code looks for something named `app` inside a file named `app`, and since it doesn't find it, it returns an ImportError.

When using `import app` you can then look for specific functions inside your `app` file. So, let's say you have one named `myFunction()` in your `app` file, and you want to use it on your `Spreads.py` file, run it by using `app.myFunction()`.